# Hibernate list deleting the records

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a many to many mapping in the hibernate and When I fetch the records eagerly there seems to be no issues, however when I try to use the FetchType.lazy it seems to delete the mapping. I am using criteria.list() to get the records and it has pagination on it.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PanicOperNotificationList",  joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "panicOperNotificationId",insertable = false,nullable = false,updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "panicNotificationListId",insertable = false,nullable = false,updatable=false) })
private Set<PanicNotificationList> notificationLists = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Try without initializing `notificationLists`. Hibernate will set it to a lazy set implementation itself and initializing it might interfere with that.

Comment: Did not work.  I do have enable_lazy_load_no_trans set to true.

Comment: Can you elaborate on " it seems to delete the mapping."? Is the data deleted from the database or is it just the lazy load that doesn't work? If the former then do you make changes to the entity? If the latter how does this manifest?

Comment: Data is getting deleted from the database. I am not making any changes, I am just using criteria.list() on the parent bean to fetch the records.

Comment: That's strange since Hibernate shouldn't allow any changes to the set. How will those notifications be added to the database? I feel we need more info about your mapping. Besides that, can you post some of the SQL queries that Hibernate executes when this happens (those are logged as debug messages to `org.hibernate.SQL`).

Comment: This is happening due to many to many relationship and I was hitting this issue (I tried to map directly using an association table).https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7971 As I could not upgrade hibernate, I used several one-to-many to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. You seem to use Hibernate 4.1.x - can't you really upgrade to 4.2.x?